# SQL Query: get the unique id/date combos based on latest dates - need speed improvement

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

Not sure how to title or ask this really. Say I am getting a result set like this on a join of two tables, one contains the `Id` (C), the other contains the `Rating` and `CreatedDate` (R) with a foreign key to the first table:

```
-----------------------------------
| C.Id | R.Rating | R.CreatedDate |
-----------------------------------
| 2    | 5        | 12/08/1981    |
| 2    | 3        | 01/01/2001    |
| 5    | 1        | 11/11/2011    |
| 5    | 2        | 10/10/2010    |
```

I want this result set (the newest ones only):

```
-----------------------------------
| C.Id | R.Rating | R.CreatedDate |
-----------------------------------
| 2    | 3        | 01/01/2001    |
| 5    | 1        | 11/11/2011    |
```

This is a very large data set, and my methods (I won't mention which so there is no bias) is very slow to do this. Any ideas on how to get this set? It doesn't necessarily have to be a single query, this is in a stored procedure.

Thank you!

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a CTE with a ROW_NUMBER():

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT ID, Rating, CreatedDate, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC) RowID
FROM [TABLESWITHJOIN]
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE RowID = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by createddate desc) as seqnum
      from table t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: I was writing an answer but answers popped up before I finished, here's a sql fiddle with supplied data and your query: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f0aab/1 if you want to use it

Comment: These were all correct, thank you!  Shaved 30 seconds off my query!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using SQL Server 2008 or later, you should consider using windowing functions. For example:

```
select ID, Rating, CreatedDate from (
    select ID, Rating, CreatedDate, 
        rowseq=ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by ID order by CreatedDate desc)
    from MyTable
) x
where rowseq = 1
```

Also, please understand that while this is an efficient query in and of itself, your overall performance depends even more heavily on the underlying tables and, in particular, the indexes and explain plans that are used when joining the tables in the first place, etc.

Comment: These were all correct, thank you!  Shaved 30 seconds off my query!